# Converting a value of more than 59 (seconds) effectively into a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I am getting 'time played' values which come as an integer in the amount of seconds.

Providing there is less than 60 seconds to be added, it's ofcourse easily done.

However, a lot of the values are more than 59 seconds and therefore cannot easily be converted into a DateTime.

An example of a value would be: `159`, which means that the 'time played' is `2 minutes and 39` seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A "number of seconds" shouldn't be stored in a `DateTime` in the first place. You should use `TimeSpan`, which makes it easy:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(159);
```

You can *add* a duration of time to any `DateTime`, of course, but that's a different matter.

(You might also want to look into my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library if you're doing any significant amount of work with dates and times... the BCL provision is somewhat underwhelming.)

Comment: Note that after you do this you can easily use formatting methods provided by `TimeSpan` to display the valute in a more human readable form than "3264 seconds".

Comment: @JonSkeet It was 1 minute 1.79 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use a `TimeSpan` not a `DateTime`.  Specifically `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure.